# Regex to match a number pattern

Tags: regex

How can I match a four digit number starting with 1 and which does not contain the number 1612
I tried

```
1[0-9]^6[0-9]^1[0-9]^2
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
(?!1612)(1[0-9]{3})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
^1(?!692)[0-9]{3}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
\\b1(?!612)\\d{3}\\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = ...
if (str.matches("1[\\d]{3}") && !"1612".equals(str)) {
    // good to go
}
```

Comment: I want single regex , may be I should remove the java tag